# class instance not iterable

Tags: python, class, iterable, hill-climbing

In my func, I have:

```
        """
        Iterates 300 times as attempts, each having an inner-loop
        to calculate the z of a neighboring point and returns the optimal                 
        """

        pointList = []
        max_p = None

        for attempts in range(300):

            neighborList = ( (x - d, y), (x + d, y), (x, y - d), (x, y + d) )

            for neighbor in neighborList:
                z = evaluate( neighbor[0], neighbor[1] )
                point = None
                point = Point3D( neighbor[0], neighbor[1], z)
                pointList += point
            max_p = maxPoint( pointList )
            x = max_p.x_val
            y = max_p.y_val
        return max_p
```

I'm not iterating over my class instance, point, but I nevertheless get:

```
    pointList += newPoint
TypeError: 'Point3D' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
pointList += point
```

`pointList` is a `list` and `point` is a `Point3D` instance. You can only add another iterable to an iterable.

You can fix it with this:

```
pointList += [point]
```

or

```
pointList.append(point)
```

In your case you do not need to assign `None` to `point`. Nor do you need to bind a variable to the new point. You can add it directly to the list like this:

```
pointList.append(Point3D( neighbor[0], neighbor[1], z))
```

Answer (score 3):

When you do the following for a `list` -

```
pointList += newPoint
```

It is similar to calling `pointList.extend(newPoint)` , and in this case `newPoint` needs to be an iterable, whose elements will get added to `pointList`.

If what you want is to simply add the element into the list, you should use `list.append()` method -

```
pointList.append(newPoint)
```